# Is there a word meaning "to expand one's vocabulary"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the action of learning more words. One that can be used like so:

> I am memorizing this list of words and their definitions to _________

Comment: Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done. List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single word for "expanding your vocabulary", however there are several options in the context of your sentence:

> I am memorizing this list of words and their definitions to _________

You could complete the phrase by using one of the suggestions from the page [To learn new skills or information](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-learn-new-skills-or-information) (Mac Millan Dictionary).

You could *master* them:

> [**master**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/master): to become skilled or proficient in the use of

Or *pick* them *up*:

> [**pick up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick%20up): to acquire by study or experience

Or *absorb* them:

> [**absorb**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absorb): to take in (knowledge, attitudes, etc.)

Finally, you could also *acquire* them:

> [**acquire**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/acquire): gain knowledge or skills

Answer (score -1):

A few years ago a Kentuckian English teacher (Is there a contradiction in terms here?), invented the word logomechanics, as an alternative to either rhetoric or wordsmith.  All three terms relate to the effective use of words, rather than collecting words.  Perhaps the impertinent compound 'word-anorak' might be more pertinent.

Comment: A candidate word needs to be accepted before it can justifiably be called a word. If 'logomechanics' appears in a respectable dictionary, please link to that.